# Why rack/test is combining hashes into one when performing POST or PUT operations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rack

In my rspec test, I defined the following array of hashes and performed a POST:

```
body = {:event => { :invitations_attributes => 
  [ {:recipient_id => 40}, {:email => 'a@a.com'}, {:facebook_id => 123456789} ] } }
post "#{@url}.json", body.reverse_merge(:auth_token => @token)
```

Based on the above, I expected the Rails server to receive "invitations_attributes" as an array of hashes.  However, the developer.log file has the following:

```
Parameters: {"auth_token"=>"RSySKfN2L8b5QPqnfGf7", "event"=>{"invitations_attributes"=>
[{"recipient_id"=>"40", "email"=>"a@a.com", "facebook_id"=>"123456789"}]}}
```

(In the parameters above, "invitation_attributes" array contains only 1 hash.)

The following curl statement:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" http://localhost:3000/api/v1/events.json -d '{"auth_token":"RSySKfN2L8b5QPqnfGf7","event":{"invitation_attributes":[{"recipient_id":40},{"email":"a@a.com"},{"facebook_id":123456789}]}}'
```

results in Rails' receiving the array of hashes intact, as evidenced by the log file entry below.

```
Parameters: {"auth_token"=>"RSySKfN2L8b5QPqnfGf7", "event"=>{"invitation_attributes"=>
[{"recipient_id"=>40}, {"email"=>"a@a.com"}, {"facebook_id"=>123456789}]}}
```

Rack/test is exhibiting this behavior for PUT operations as well as POST.

Why is rack/test combining the 3 hashes into 1 rather than sending the array exactly as it is defined?  Is there a setting which will cause rack to exhibit the behavior I expected?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to ensure that each hash contains each key by inserting nil value placeholder keys as follows:

```
body = {:event => { :invitations_attributes => [
  {:recipient_id => 40, :recipient_email => nil, :recipient_facebook_id => nil},
  {:recipient_email => user.email, :recipient_id => nil, :recipient_facebook_id => nil}, 
  {:recipient_facebook_id => new_unused_facebook_id, :recipient_email => nil, :recipient_id => nil}  ] } }
```

The hash above does cause the server to receive 3 separate hashes within the array.  However, inserting placeholder keys is inconvenient and should not be required.  Furthermore, scenarios where a controller acts differently based on the *presence* of a such a key (albeit uncommon), cannot be tested.